# Multiple functions in a JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have multiple functions to my JS file.  Just not sure how to do that, since I'm really inexperienced with JavaScript.  Here's what I have.

```
$(function(){
  $('.incentives').hide();

  $('.incentives-click').on("click", function(){
    $('.incentives').fadeToggle();
  });

    $('.incentivesB').hide();

  $('.incentivesB-click').on("click", function(){
    $('.incentivesB').fadeToggle();
  });

})();
```

I'm trying to add a bit that will make an image change when I hover over it.

```
$(function onHover(){
    $(".button").attr('src', 'images/donate2.png');
)}

$(function offHover(){
    $(".button").attr('src', 'images/donate1.png');
)}
```

**BONUS**

Also trying to get the image (.incentives-click) to toggle when clicked as well.  I have an idea about how to go about this, but will appreciate if anyone wanted to help with this as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `.toggle()`?

Comment: I have a little.  Like I said I'm new to this.  I was going to use that for the Bonus bit: changing the image when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.button').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/donate2.png')
    }, function(){
        $(this). attr('src', 'images/donate1.png');
    });

    $('.button').on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggle(function(){
             #change_image1
        }, function(){
             #change_image2
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks good, but I can't quite get the hover aspect working.  Not sure why.

here's the HTML

`<center><a class="button" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=TD43XA78T9CTQ" target="_blank"><img src="/images/donate1.png" title="Donate" alt="Donate"></a></center>`

Comment: @user2036459 Why do you set src for anchor? You wanna set the src for thr img. In JS it should be like this: `$('img', this).attr(...);`

Comment: @user2036459 and it might be a better pratice to put both anchor and img in the same level under a div

Comment: I just copied the link from PayPal, and switched in my image.

Comment: YEP.  The weird <a> <img> thing was the culprit.  Didn't even think of that.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2036459 FYI, if you change img to be on the same level with anchor , the selector should be `$(this).siblings('img')`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [jQuery plugin which does something similar to what you need](http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2011/11/26/jquery-collapsible-panel-plugin/). You should be able to modify it to suit your needs with minimal effort.

You could also start with one of the jQuery plugin boilerplates such as:

- [jQuery Boilerplate.com](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/)
- [jQuery plugin boilerplate](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/)
- [My CollapsiblePanel plugin on Github](https://github.com/Echilon/Miscellaneous/tree/master/CollapsiblePanel)

Comment: A link to your plugin is not a good answer. Post the code. If the link ever goes away, this answer is useless.